# Is this how REST response is sent from server side (Yii2) to mobile side?

Tags: rest, curl, yii2, jsonresult, jsonresponse

I'm building a REST-full API in Yii2 framework. I'm sending the data in JSON format and returning response in JSON response as well.

I'm making the **test request with the call via cmd**:

```
C:\Windows\system32>curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://<path_to_host>/www/users/register -d "{\"user_firstname\":\"Name\", \"user_lastname\":\"LastName\",\"user_email\":\"test@email.com\",\"user_username\":\"usernameTest\",\"user_password\":\"123456\",\"user_is_eighteen\":\"true\"}
```

with this call the corresponding action is called and my code is executed. Then at the end of the logic **in the called controller** I'm trying to send the response as the following:

```
.
.
creating variables $model and $error_msg
.
.
header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK '); 
header('Content-type: application/json'); 

$response = Yii::$app->response;
$response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON; 
$response->statusCode = $200; 
$response->data = [ 
                    'data' => $model,
                    'errors' => $error_msg, 
                  ];        

Yii::$app->end();
```

so as said before, this I'm testing the call via cmd:

[image]

Later this request will be created (and responses will be received) by mobile application. This is what I got as a result from the cmd, and **I'm wondering will this be enough for receiving the JSON response at the mobile side?** (since I'm not sure how to test it)

Comment: Yes, it should be. No idea why you are both setting the header 2 times though. 1 time with the header function the other with $response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;

Comment: So that means that I can remove the line: **header('Content-type: application/json');** is that correct?

Comment: Correct, use $response to format header responses. It'll save you from headache.